# Does using case class or Option lead to increase in memory consumption

Tags: performance, scala, memory

I have a job, where I am running pregal algorithm (GraphX). 
The message that I transmit and process, across the nodes is of the form Vector[(Double,Long)]. This job succeeds. 
However, if I convert this to Vector[(Option[Double],Option[Long])] , since sometimes these values might not be present and I want to use None instead of -1 as a default value. Then the job fails throwing out of memory issues ( GC overhead reached) .

The graph is pretty huge, with about 80 million nodes, consuming about 250 Gigs. 
I tried increasing executor memory, the heap fraction .etc

Just a couple of questions

1) Does using a case class cause performance degradation, than primitives ?

2) Likewise does using Scala option cause any performance degradation ?

Comment: primitives will always be much faster and use less memory than using objects.  Java objects have an overhead of at least 8 bytes. In most cases the trade off is worth it. Also consider specialization.  Tuple2 is specialized for primitive types, Option is not.

Comment: How exactly do you use specialization for this case ?

Comment: You don't, it's up to the creator of a class to specialize it, not the person using it.